# How do I save a file using the Eclipse compare editor

Tags: eclipse, diff

I can't seem to find a way to save the changes I make to project files using the two-way compare of two local project file folders. I can step through the differences and copy changes from left to right, but there's no way, as far as I can tell, to save those changes. I looked at the files outside of Eclipse after I copy changes left to right and they are not being updated.

Here's a help site explaining what I'm doing http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-25.htm  it sayz 'You can save changes to resources that are made in the comparison editor.' but doesn't say how...

I can just copy and paste the contents of the merged file into a new editor window but this seems like a silly way to go about this. I guess I could also create a diff patch and apply it to my project as well...

Comment: Does ctrl-s not work for you?

Comment: ctrl+s does not work, Save also grayed out in the File menu...

Comment: Ctrl+s works properly here... (I'm using Indigo, and remember of this working since a lot of time ago). What types of files are you comparing?

Comment: Btw, couldn't the files be read-only or locked (in SVN, for example)?.

Comment: nope, no version control system involved, just two filesystem folders. the files are writable as I just opened the file in an editor window and copy/pasted the merged file from the compare window... I'm using Indigo on Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you modify the files, in Eclipse, separately and save them? Also, couldn't it be any file permission issues? I mean, maybe when you do the merge yourself, you're sudo'ing something that Eclipse can't. I would also try a clean download of Eclipse to try it out

Comment: @EvertonAgner, thanks for sticking with this. I'm sure this is not a file permissions issue. What I ended up doing was the compare, copying my changes from left to right, open the same file with an eclipse editor, ctrl+a everything, and copy/paste that into the editor...

Comment: Okay, I'm out of ideas... I'm curious to know what caused this. Maybe only a clean download can fix this.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that using *nix command `diff` is a piece of cake:

```
diff -rupN original/ new/ > original.patch
```

as stated in the "[The Ten Minute Guide to diff and patch](http://jungels.net/articles/diff-patch-ten-minutes.html)"